# Random sampling from a known data set

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to randomly select 6 samples from a known data set(n=35) 10,000 times. I feel like this is a basic code, but I can't find it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I need to estimate the probability of not detecting houston toads when 6 surveys are conducted over 10,000 iterations. I have a data set of 35 probabilities.

Comment: What has that to do with iphone?

Comment: I just needed a tag and wasn't sure which to use. I'm typing this from my iphone.

Comment: Any perfered Programming Language? As tag, usable too.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS, you can do this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

- (id)randomElement:(NSArray *)array {

    NSInteger index = arc4random() % array.count;
    return [array objectAtIndex:index];
}
```

arc4random promises a uniform distribution of pseudo-random numbers.  This can also be made into a category method on array dropping the parameter.